# Angular material slide transition in side nav?

Tags: html, angularjs, css, css-transitions, angular-material

When i'm click on settings it's navigate to inner navigation menu and after that here back main menu option.

For that i'm trying to implement Slide transition in side nav using angular material , but it's not showing the slide transition effect in side nav.

`Angular material slide nav Plnkr ::`http://plnkr.co/edit/tAocrJglxnLs3mMPqAnb

slide transition : When we click on settings it's navigate to inner menu and then click on back navigate to main menu. For that need slide transition effect.

For example : http://plnkr.co/edit/o37kGQByrXX9jdIxuIXZ

Any one suggest on slide transition effect.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Please elaborate what exactly you want to do?

Comment: @RahulArora Thanks for quick reply. I added more description and sample plnkr.

Comment: What is wrong with the plunkr your provided ?

Comment: In that plunkr slide transition effect is not working in inner menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ksfo7fnSB0c4DH6egE3S?p=preview

```
<md-content class="main-ctr" ng-controller="RightCtrl" class="md-padding">
```

and mainmenu and submenu 2 other classes, their positions are absolute so they can slide frictionless

Comment: should work now , add a class donotshow at the beginning to prevent slide of submenu

Comment: Thanks Piyush, excellent Answer. I am trying to implement in one more inner submenu ,but it's not working.
When we are click on settings it's navigate to submenu, In that sub menu i have search button, click on that search button it's navigate to inner search input and then click on close/cross button it's navigate to back submenu. For that i tried but it's not working. 
Can you please suggest me. the issue is in same plnkr.

Comment: i dont see any search button in the submenu using the same plunkr above ,may be if you update the fiddle

Comment: check this fork of your fiddle http://plnkr.co/edit/FZqQgdtglx04KZkPA4Od?p=preview

Comment: yeah, But here we have search in submenu click on that it's show other input with close button. When we click close it's navigate back, In between that same slide  transition effect. that i am trying to implement. but it's not working.

Comment: you want to slide search  locations with submenu header or complete submenu?

Comment: Only submenu header part.

Answer (score 0):

add classes to the menu as

`<div ng-show="submenu" class="submenu">`
`<div ng-show="mainMenu" class="mainmenu">`

and the css will be

```
.submenu.ng-hide,
.mainmenu.ng-hide{
  display: block !important;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .35s linear;
 }

.submenu,
.mainmenu{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .35s linear;
 }
```

Comment: I tried that but it's not a slide effect and getting position issue. follow the plnk : http://plnkr.co/edit/1boZbKdAf36Fk7UePghe?p=preview

Comment: tried to work on that plunkr. but it's not supporting use of '!important'. and what kind of transition u need? left to right?

Comment: Can u please give a jsfiddle link. plunkr editing is little difficult